# can't host my flask web app using pythonanywhere

Tags: python, numpy, flask, wsgi, pythonanywhere

```
2024-01-11 09:47:43,839: Error running WSGI application
2024-01-11 09:47:43,841: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
2024-01-11 09:47:43,841:   File "/var/www/nethmini99_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2024-01-11 09:47:43,841:     from main_app import app as application  # noqa
2024-01-11 09:47:43,842: 
2024-01-11 09:47:43,842:   File "/home/Nethmini99/mysite/main_app.py", line 2, in <module>
2024-01-11 09:47:43,842:     import numpy as np
# 2024-01-11 09:47:43,842: ***************************************************[wsgi.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A49tm.png)
2024-01-11 09:47:43,842: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
2024-01-11 09:47:43,842: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug: 
2024-01-11 09:47:43,842: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
2024-01-11 09:47:43,842: ***************************************************
2024-01-11 09:47:49,608: 
2024-01-12 05:56:45,849:   **********************************************
```

Comment: Is `numpy` included in `requirements.txt` (or other dependecies file)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own virtual environment on PythonAnywhere and install the required packages there.